# Weird behaviour of a bash script

Tags: bash

Here's a snippet:

```
var=`ls | shuf | head -2 | xargs cat | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | shuf | tr -d '\n'`
```

This will select two random files from the current directory, combine their contents, shuffle them, and assign the result to var. This works fine most of the time, but about once in a thousand cases, instead just the output of `ls` is bound to var (*It's not just the output, see EDIT II)*. What could be the explanation?

Some more potentially relevant facts:

- the directory contains at least two files
- there are only text files in the directory
- file names don't contain spaces
- the files are anywhere from 5 to about 1000 characters in length
- the snippet is a part of a larger script that it ran two instances in parallel
- bash version: `GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`
- uname: `Linux 2.6.35-28-generic-pae #50-Ubuntu`

**EDIT:** I ran the snippet by itself a couple of thousand times with no errors. Then I tried running it with various other parts of the whole script. Here's a configuration that produces errors:

```
cd dir_with_text_files
var=`ls | shuf | head -2 | xargs cat | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | shuf | tr -d '\n'`
cd ..
```

There are several hundred lines of the script between the `cd`s, but this is the minimal configuration to reproduce the error.  Note that the anomalous output binds to var the output of the current directory, not `dir_with_text_files`.

**EDIT II:** I've been looking at the outputs in more detail. The `ls` output doesn't appear alone, it's along with with two shuffled files (between their contents, or after or before them, intact). But it gets better; let me set up the stage to talk about particular directories.

```
[~/projects/upload] ls -1
checked // dir
lines   // dir, the files to shuffle are here
pages   // also dir
proxycheck
singlepost
uploader
indexrefresh
t
tester
```

So far, I've seen the output of `ls` ran from `upload`, but now I saw the output of `ls */*` (also ran from `upload`). It was in the form of "someMangledText `ls` moreMangledText `ls */*` finalBatchOfText". Is it possible that the sequence `ls` that undoubtedly was generated was somehow executed?

Comment: What is the rate at which this happens approximately? I just tried just now a few tens of times, and it worked fine for me every time.

Comment: I ran the script 50000 times and no error occured. To test it automatically I generated some files with your specification which contain all letters but x. The filenames have an x in it. So, if var has an x in it, this will indicate an error. Are you sure that the surrounding script is not messing with var? Maybe you can post some of it, too?

Comment: Interesting problem! As @sl0815 did it 5000 time without problems, maybe it will help post the exact version of bash and who OS you are using. (If you're using AIX, it wouldn't completely surprise me ;-> ). As this doesn't feel like a production code problem, maybe you should just test var and ignore it when it is ls output. Good luck.

Comment: @Victor: Each instance executes the snippet once about every twenty seconds.

Comment: @sl0815: The var is just printed to stderr, then immediately used in curl as form data.

Comment: @VladVivdovitch : Incidentally, excellently stated problem description. If I could vote on it more I would ;-)... I guess at this point, I would wrap the problem code with `set -vx; ... code ... ; set +vx`, and redirect like `script > tmpOutput 2>&1`, and see if you can find some clues. Good luck!

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the symptoms with *just* that snippet running? Otherwise, I suspect that the real problem is elsewhere in the scripts. Post code and file names with which you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VladVivdovitch: could you change the above command to var=`ls | shuf | head -2 | xargs cat | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | shuf | tr -d '\n'; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}">&2` and post the output in case of an error? The output should be all 0s (when no error occurs). If it is all 0s in the case of an error, then we can rule out faulty pipes, i think.

Comment: @Vlad: I apologize; by "rate" I meant the approximate percentage of times the error occurs compared to the total amount of times.

Comment: @Victor: Then it's as I have stated in the question, once in two or three thousand times.

Comment: @sl0815: Ran the script 10000 times (with the `cd`s), some errors, no broken pipes).

Comment: Any reason you're using ls, as opposed to bash builtins (ie: `printf '%s\n' *`, which would require no `exec` call)? Extra points if you can get the rest of the pipeline to support nulls rather than newlines (which printf will do with `printf '%s\0' *`) -- right now, filenames with newlines (yes, they're legal) will break your code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: "the snippet is a part of a larger script that it ran two instances in parallel"?

Comment: @GargantuChet: I launch it once uploading data to one account, then I launch another instance in a separate shell, uploading data to my backup account. The contrived randomisation is there just because I had such a whim and is not necessary for proper function.

Answer (score 2):

No problems here either. 
I would also rewrite the above to this:

```
sed 's:\(.\):\1\n:g' < <(shuf -e * | head -2 | xargs cat) | shuf | tr -d '\n'
```

Do not use `ls` to list a directory's content, use `*`.
Moreover, do some debugging. Use a shebang followed by:

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
```

and run the script like this:

```
/bin/bash -x /path/to/script
```

and do **inspect** the output.
Instead of debugging the whole script, you can surround just the part that seems to be problematic with `-x`

```
set -x
...code that may have problems...
set +x
```

so that the output focuses on that part of the code.
Also, use the `pipefail` option.

> Some definitions:
>
> - `-e` : Exit immediately if a simple command exits with a non-zero status, unless the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of a && or || list, or if the command's return status is being inverted using !. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits
> - `-x` : Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments
> - `pipefail` : If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the pipeline exit successfully

Comment: I don't really mind being downvoted, I'd like to know why though. That's what this whole thing is all about, sharing knowledge and helping each other.

Comment: That looks like useful debugging advice.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes you may also clear the environment using `env -i` and filter out non-printable characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash --

set -ef
set -o pipefail

unset IFS PATH LC_ALL
IFS=$' \t\n'
PATH="$(PATH=/bin:/usr/bin getconf PATH)"
LC_ALL=C
export IFS PATH LC_ALL

#var="$((find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | shuf -z -n 2 | xargs -0 cat) | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | shuf | tr -d '\n')"

var="$((find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | shuf -z -n 2 | xargs -0 cat) | tr -cd '[[:print:]]' | grep -o '.' | shuf | tr -d '\n')"
```

Before running the script you may also disable the GNU readline library and ! style history expansion:

```
bash --noediting
set +H
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you say wrt to your failure rates, and given the success of the other tests performed by the posters above, it sounds like a problem that could be caused by an occasional directory-change failure.  Is the directory you're accessing in this script mounted from a remote machine by chance?  If so, it might just be a small and temporary network-related failure that's not being handled properly.  (Just a guess.)

Comment: Nope, it's local, on the same partition.

Comment: one other thing that got to my mind was that you could be running something in the background (foo &) that happens to output the results of its operation at the same time the results of your command come up. However if you actually run the command by itself and still got that problem then that's higly unlikely a situation. 
I'll say again using `ls` isn't safe, try using `*` instead.